# Finding variance from bell curve

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

[image]Find variance from the graph given. I know the mean is 6 but I have no idea how to find the variance using this graph

Comment: You might be expected to assume that this is a normal density whose value at $\mu \pm \sigma$ is smaller than the peak value. Use your knowledge of the normal density function to figure out _how much_ smaller. You have deduced that $\mu=6$; now figure out where the curve has dropped down to the appropriate fraction. That will give you an estimate of $\mu\pm \sigma$. A measuring scale and a calculator will come in handy.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi} } e^{-\frac{(x-6)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$ be the pdf.  From the graph we see that $f(6) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi} } \approx .08$, and you can use that equation to solve for $\sigma^2.$

Comment: You're off by a factor of 10 but that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

$\mu\pm\sigma$ are the inflection points: the points where the graph stops getting steeper and starts getting less steep.